# Scikitlearn - score dataset after cross-validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm learning about cross validation using scikit-learn (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html)

My code:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm

iris = datasets.load_iris()

# prepare sets
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(iris.data, iris.target, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

# create model
clf1 = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)

# train model
scores = cross_val_score(clf1, x_train, y_train, cv=5)

# accuracy on train data
print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))

# accuracy on yet-unseen data
print clf1.score(x_test, y_test)
```

I understand that with cross-validation we can use whole dataset to train and validate as in example in scikit doc. What if I want to score data after cross-validate? I assume my model is trained after learning with cross-validation. While using `score()` I get

```
raise NotFittedError(msg % {'name': type(estimator).__name__})
sklearn.utils.validation.NotFittedError: This SVC instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.
```

In doc there is method paragraph 3.1.1.1 where `cross_val_predict` is mentioned and I could use it but why I need cv argument (which is fold number) while I just want to check accuracy of trained model?

I would be thankful for any hint.

Comment: There are many types of scores its for you to decide which one you want. You can check the sci kit learn docs But for this situation You can check out cross validation metrics :http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html , hope this helps !@PawelPawel

Comment: `cross_val_score` does not fit the model object you pass as an argument, but creates copies so as to keep each fold independent. You have to actually fit the model now manually. Also, do not split your data into training and testing sets *before* passing it to `cross_val_score`, that does that for you...

Comment: You need to understand what the purpose of cross-validation is - it's for getting an estimate of a *generalizable metric*, that is, how will your model perform on unseen data. You don't "train a model with cross-validation",

Comment: But why do you want a score ? To know the accuracy for your cross validation?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Good point but why then cross-validation is so useful in case of small data sets? It gives metric and what's more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a code that gets the job done with a step-by-step explanation of how it works.

To begin with, let us import the necessary modules:

```
In [204]: from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, StratifiedKFold

In [205]: from sklearn import datasets

In [206]: from sklearn import svm
```

You should make certain you have installed **scikit-learn 0.18**, otherwise the following code might not work. Please, notice I'm using `sklearn.model_selection` instead of `sklearn.cross_validation` because the latter is deprecated in version 0.18.

Then we load the iris dataset and create arrays `X` and `y` with the features and labels, respectively

```
In [207]: iris = datasets.load_iris()

In [208]: X, y = iris.data, iris.target
```

In the next step we create an instance of the C-Support Vector Classification class:

```
In [209]: clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
```

Now we create a stratified K-Folds validator which splits the dataset into 5 disjoint subsets, namely A, B, C, D and E. These five folds are stratified, which means that the proportion of samples of each class in A, B, C, D and E are the same as in the overall dataset.

```
In [210]: skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=0)
```

Finally, we estimate the generalization accuracy through 5 classification trials:

```
In [211]: scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=skf)

In [212]: scores
Out[212]: array([ 0.9667,  1.    ,  0.9667,  0.9667,  1.    ])

In [213]: scores.mean()
Out[213]: 0.98000000000000009
```

5-Folds cross-validation can be summarized as follows:

```
Classification No.   Training Samples   Test Samples   Accuracy
1                    A + B + C + D      E              0.9667
2                    A + B + C + E      D              1.
3                    A + B + D + E      C              0.9667
4                    A + C + D + E      B              0.9667
5                    B + C + D + E      A              1.
```

It clearly emerges from the table above that each sample is used four times for training and is tested only once.

Replies to your additional comments:

1. The main advantage of cross-validation is that all the samples are used for both training and testing, i.e. cross-validation provides you with the maximum modelling and testing capability, which is particularly important when the dataset is small.
2. One way of avoiding overfitting is by using different samples for training and testing.
3. A common approach for chosing the model parameters consists in validating the model for different parameter sets and selecting those values that maximize the classification accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for so detailed answer. I got the idea from the comments about how it works. It was my misunderstanding because I had in mind that cross validation is actually way of learning. The question for me now is, how cross validation is used? Why it helps in case of small data sets? Because we can use whole dataset for training? Cross-validation is used for choosing right parameters for model so as to avoid overfitting? It seems to me like this after reading this example:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/exercises/plot_cv_diabetes.html Thank you for answer!